# Angular 5 authentication for 1 user

Tags: angular, authentication

I am building a webapp with Angular and the website is fully accessible to everyone but I created a component `adminOverview` with a rout to it `/admin` with on my website no links to this route and I want to create some kind of authentication with 1 user to only see this component which will be filled with data from my firebase application but I have no clue how to go forward from here.

- What tools frameworks can I use, I only need 1 login so not too
  complicated?
- How do I define that a certain route is only for authenticated users?
- I get and set from my firebase database from the non authenticated part too, do I need to change something in my settings there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tools..,you can use some templates such as CoreUI[enter link description here](https://coreui.io/demo/AngularJS_Demo/#!/dashboard) or mdbootstrap. There will a login page and you have to use local storage and route to main page once you login. I have given a example for you.I hope this helps !!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MyDataService} from '../my-data.service';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
 })

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router: Router, private user:MyDataService){}

ngOnInit(){
}
  loginUser(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(e);
   var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
   var password = e.target.elements[1].value;

   if(username == 'root' && password == 'socrates'){
   this.user.setUserLoggedIn();
   this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
}
}
}
```

```html
<div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-group mb-0">
          <div class="card p-4">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
              <form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="input-group mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Login</button>
                </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```